# ElasticSearch Make Field non-searchable from java

Tags: java, elasticsearch, resthighlevelclient

I am currently working on elastic search through my java Application . I know how to index the Java pojo using RestHighLevelClient. How i can  make search only on new fields not the complete pojo.?

```
    public class Employee{ 
        private long id;
        private String name;
        private String designation;
        private String address;       //want to index but not searchable in elastic search    
     }
```

My Code for indexing is below which is working fine:

```
 public String saveToEs(Employee employee) throws IOException {
    Map<String, Object> map = objectMapper.convertValue(employee, Map.class);

    IndexRequest indexRequest =
        new IndexRequest(INDEX, TYPE, employee.getId().toString()).source(map, XContentType.JSON);


    IndexResponse indexResponse = client.index(indexRequest, RequestOptions.DEFAULT);
```

I need to do this in java .Any help please or good link ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Writing another answer for `RestHighLevelClient` As another answer is useful for people not using the Rest client and adding this in the first answer makes it too long.

**Note: you are passing the `type` which is deprecated in ES 7.X and I am using the ES 7.X version, so my code is according to 7.X.**

```
        CreateIndexRequest request = new CreateIndexRequest("employee");
        Map<String, Object> name = new HashMap<>();
        name.put("type", "text");
        Map<String, Object> address = new HashMap<>();
        address.put("type", "text");
        address.put("index", false);

        Map<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<>();
        properties.put("name", name);
        properties.put("address", address);
        Map<String, Object> mapping = new HashMap<>();
        mapping.put("properties", properties);
        request.mapping(mapping);
        CreateIndexResponse createIndexResponse = client.indices().create(request, RequestOptions.DEFAULT);
```

### Important points

- I've used only 2 fields for illustration purpose, one of which is `address` field which is not searchable, and to do that I used, `address.put("index", false);` , while `name` is searchable field and there this option isn't present.
- I've created `index mapping` using the Map method which is available in this [official ES doc](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-rest/master/java-rest-high-create-index.html).
- you can check the mapping created by this code, using [mapping REST API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-get-mapping.html).
- Below is the mapping generated for this code in my system and you can see, `index: false` is added in the address field.

> ```
> {
>   "employee": {
>     "mappings": {
>       "properties": {
>         "address": {
>           "type": "text",
>           "index": false
>         },
>         "name": {
>           "type": "text"
>         }
>       }
>     }
>   }
> }
> ```

- You can just use the same search JSON mentioned in the previous answer, to test that it's not searchable.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [index option](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-index.html#mapping-index) as false on the address field, which is by default true to make it unsearchable. As mention in the same official ES link:

> The index option controls whether field values are indexed. It accepts
>   true or false and defaults to true. Fields that are not indexed are
>   not queryable.

Let me show you how can you test it using the REST API and then the java code(using rest-high level client) to accomplish it.

### Mapping

```
{
    "mappings": {
        "properties": {
            "id": {
                "type": "long"
            },
            "name": {
                "type": "text"
            },
            "designation": {
                "type": "text"
            },
            "address": {
                "type": "text",
                "index" : false --> made `index` to false
            }
        }
    }
}
```

### Index few docs

```
{
    "address" : "USA",
    "name"  : "Noshaf",
    "id" :  234567892,
    "designation" : "software engineer"
}

{
    "address" : "USA california state",
    "name"  : "opster",
    "id" :  234567890,
    "designation" : "software engineer"
}
```

### A simple match search query in JSON format on `address` field

```
{
    "query": {
        "match" : {
            "address" : "USA"
        }
    }
}
```

### Exception from Elasticsearch clearly mention, it's not searchable

> "caused_by": {
>                           "type": "illegal_argument_exception",
>                           "reason": "**Cannot search on field [address] since it is** not indexed."
>                       }